# There are currently no network adapters with network optimization available

Tags: networking, virtualization, scvmm

I'm setting up a 2 node Hyper-V cluster and when I try to migrate a virtual from one host to the other via VMM, I get a  "There are currently no network adapters with network optimization available" error that causes a failure.

The two servers are identical in every way (hardware, drivers, settings, etc)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The "There are currently no network adapters with network optimization available" should only be an error if you have the "Enable Network Optimizations" checked on the VM networking page. If you uncheck that, the error should go away.